# Check Touch out of relative layout

Tags: android

I want to check touch `x,y position` in my `activity` to know is it out of My `RelativeLayout` or not.
i override the `onTouch`event for activity but its not working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to do something like this.. in `Activity` you Have to override

```
dispatchTouchEvent
```

so in your `onCreate` find your view

```
RelativeLayout  yourLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayout);
```

and then

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        float touchPointX = ev.getX();
        float touchPointY = ev.getY();
        int[] coordinates = new int[2];
        yourLayout.getLocationOnScreen(coordinates);
        if (touchPointX < coordinates[0] || touchPointX > coordinates[0] + yourLayout.getWidth() || touchPointY < coordinates[1] || touchPointY > coordinates[1] + yourLayout.getHeight()){
            //Do Your ACTION
   }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```